# Как выводить данные из базы в течении часа?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Есть необходимость вывода данных из базы по определенному времени и держать это в течении установленного времени.

В базе есть столбец с временем старта в формате 17:00:00 (timeonair) лимит который нужно показывать данные в минутах от 60 до 120 минут (time_limit).

Как сделать это более красиво чем ниже?

пробовал как-то так:

```
    // Вясняем текущи день недели и время //
    $d=array('Воскресенье','Понедельник','Вторник','Среда','Четверг','Пятница','Суббота');
    $dw=$d[date('w')];
    $t=date('H:i:s',time());
    $ns=(substr($t,0,2)*3600)+(substr($t,3,5)*60)+substr($t,6,8);

        $result33=mysql_query("SELECT id,dayweek,timeonair,time_limit,time_air FROM radioshow WHERE dayweek='$dw' and active='yes'",$db);

        while($myrow33=mysql_fetch_assoc($result33)){

            $ti=$myrow33['timeonair'];
            $t_start=(substr($ti,0,2)*3600)+(substr($ti,3,5)*60)+substr($ti,6,8);
            $t_stop=$t_start+$myrow33['time_limit']*60;

                if($ns>$t_start && $ns<$t_stop){
                    $id_radioshow = $myrow33['id'];
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function display_date($time) {

    if ($time > time() - 60) $out .= 'Сейчас';
    elseif ($time > time() - 3600) {
        $minutes = floor((time() - $time) / 60);
        $out .= $minutes.' мин. назад';
     }elseif ($time > time() - 86400) {
        $hours = floor((time() - $time) / 3600);
        $out .= $hours.' ч. назад';
    }
return $out;
}
```

что-то типа так